# Eliminate a public script from tradingview

Tags: pine-script

I want to change or eliminate a public script from tradingview that I published, How can I do do this?.

Answer (score 0):

Tradingview does **not** remove ideas and scripts after they are published. But you can delete your publication within 15 minutes. Otherwise, you can no longer delete it. [FAQ](https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/FAQ#How_to_delete_an_idea.2Fscript.3F)

To update a script, simply click on the `Publish Script` button and select `Update Existing Script` and choose the script you want to update. After that you can publish a new version.

[image]